# How to lock and unlock game levels?

Tags: menu, gui

In my level menu (I'm using libGDX), I would like to lock and unlock game levels.

The idea is that after finishing the previous level, the player is allowed to tackle the next one.

Can someone point me to an example?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, this question is unrelated to libGDX in its core. Implementing this is a matter of your own application logic. Somewhere you need to store the progress of the player and based on those values, determine which levels are available. Based on your target platform different best practices on how best store data are available.

If you definitely want libGDX to take care of that, one option would be to use the [Preference interface](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Preferences.html) of libGDX.

Some links that might help:

- [Android internal memory storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)
- [Similar question on the BadLogicGames forums](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1796)

Whether a level is available or not, should then be made visually clear to the player, e. g. via different colours:

- Level icons/images/etc. that are available could be coloured.
- Unavailable ones only be displayed in gray scale.

This can even be combined with an green "ok" sign and a red crossed sign to make it even easier for the user to distinguish the two states.